# Will Richard Branson be setting any space firsts by beating Jeff Bezos' launch date?

Tags: record, blue-origin, virgin-galactic

Virgin Galactic is [now saying they will launch Richard Branson on July 11](https://arstechnica.com/science/2021/07/game-on-sir-richard-branson-will-attempt-to-go-to-space-on-july-11/)

> Dubbed the "Unity 22" mission, this flight on the VSS Unity spacecraft will carry a full crew of two pilots, Dave Mackay and Michael Masucci, and four mission specialists, including Branson. "Building on the success of the company's most recent spaceflight in May, Unity 22 will focus on cabin and customer experience objectives," the company said in a statement.

This beats Jeff Bezos into space, currently scheduled for July 20

> The timing of this flight is significant, because a July 11 mission would allow Branson to beat Amazon founder Jeff Bezos to space. Bezos has said he will fly on the first human flight of the New Shepard spacecraft, developed and tested by his Blue Origin rocket company. That mission is set for July 20.

Ignoring the publicity portion here, is there a space "first" to either launch?

- [Dennis Tito was the first private citizen to buy his way into space in 2001](https://www.space.com/11492-space-tourism-pioneer-dennis-tito.html)
- SpaceX is the [first company to use a privately owned spacecraft to launch people into space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_Dragon_Demo-2)
- [Virgin Galactic has already flown people to 80km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Unity_VP-03)

Is there anything else either flight will do first that Branson would like to be under his name instead of Bezos?

Comment: First person surnamed Branson into space? First person who founded a record company into space? How trivial of "firsts" do you want?

Comment: First person to finance his own vehicle (or its company) to space?

Comment: first to 80km, and call it "space"?(rest of the world is of opinion that 100km = space)

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't necessarily want trivial. Something new is happening here and it will likely be recorded in history as "Richard Branson was the first to do X" as a major standalone achievement. I am aware [how trivial that list can get](https://xkcd.com/1122/)

Comment: @PcMan USAF gives astronaut pins to 50-milers (80467 m).

Comment: @RussellBorogove yep. For airplanes. And an additional requirement was that you need to be an active member of the air force. Branson used a big crowbar and some vaseline, to make an outdated and insular qualification work for him, but tacks on the international label for what he does. It.....cheapens the accomplishment, to have to bend the rules like that. Like running a 4-minute mile, but your mile is 1600m long "because that's the size of the track at the stadium"

Comment: @PcMan the civilian X-15 pilots were given astronaut wings in 2005. They were not active members of the air force. https://www.nasa.gov/missions/research/X-15_wings.html Also, the SpaceShips are airplanes.

Comment: First billionaire to make the wall of the Happy Bottom Riding Club?  (Yeah, I know it burned down, but you know what I mean.  He's still a pudknocker.)

Comment: @DrSheldon Guy Laliberte (first clown in space https://www.ctvnews.ca/polopoly_fs/1.4094504.1536948978!/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_1020/image.jpg) appears to be a billionaire now. No idea about then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Richard Branson will be there first person launched into space* on a rocket he owns/built**.

*The 80km altitude he will reach is a contested definition of space.

**The rocket is owned/built by the Virgin Galactic, but he is founder and largest shareholder.

This is probably the least contrived record to be set.

Comment: This article agrees with your conclusion. http://www.parabolicarc.com/2021/07/01/branson-vs-bezos-let-the-spin-and-the-shade-begin/